# Why smart quotes look garbled in html

Tags: html

This is my htmlcode

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
</head>

<body>
“”
</body>

</html>
```

This is what I see in firefox â€œâ€

I wonder why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To write characters outside the standard ASCII set (which is common among almost all encodings) without using HTML entities, you have to make sure that the file is actually saved using the encoding that you specify in the meta tag.

Your page is saved as UTF-8 (the default), which means that those characters will be wrong when the browser tries to decode them as Windows-1252.

Comment: Thanks. So how should I change the file so the decoding is UTF8

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the HTML entities for smart quotes: `&#8220;` for the left, `&#8221;` on the right.

More info [here](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/quotes-in-html.html).